# nodejs with tap: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

Tags: node.js, unit-testing, circular-dependency, tap

I'm pretty new to node development and have the issue mentioned in the headline. I figured out, that this is probably a circular dependency issue. But I really don't get why.

Maybe you can help?

Here is the first part of my application that works.
I have a simple abstract class like this:

```
export abstract class AbstractApplication {
    abstract beforeStart(): void
    abstract afterStart(): void
}
```

Then I have a second class that extends from that AbstractApplication:

```
export class App extends AbstractApplication {
  //implement the specific methods from AbstractApplication here and do things
  async startApp(): void {
     //do things here
  }
}
```

Inside this same file, I create an instance of the App class and export it into the module like this:

```
const app: App = new App()
module.exports = app
```

Then, inside another file, the server.js, I require this app and start it like this:

```
const app = require("./src/App")
app.startApp()
```

And if I run `npm run start` which calls `node server.js` everything works and the App runs.

Now I have a seperate file that contains a third class that extends from the App class like this:

```
export class TestSuite extends App {
    async startApp(): Promise<void> {
        console.log("READY")
    }
}
```

So as you can see, I take the app class but I override the startApp function.
Inside this same file I do the same thing I did in the App file before:

```
const testSuite = new TestSuite()
module.exports = testSuite
```

Then in a last file, I'm doing this:

```
const testSuite = require("./TestSuite")
testSuite.startApp()
```

If I now change my npm start to `node theOtherFileWithTestSuiteStart.js` and run npm run start, everything works also fine.

Now, the last file which contains the `testSuite.startApp()`should contain test functions that depend on that application, just something simple as

```
const testSuite = require("./TestSuite")
testSuite.startApp()

test('requests the "/" route', function () {
    //test something here
})
```

And when I run this with tap, then I get the error above: TypeError: Class extends value undefined is not a constructor or null

The interesting thing is: If I extend the TestSuite class from AbstractApplication, I at least get an error that the test is unfinished (which may be okay because of dummy implementation). If I extend it from the App class, this error occures.

Any ideas?